# JavaScript: Variable in class to be searched

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I'm pretty new to javascript, so this is probably a fairly easy question. However, part of the problem why I can't fix it myself is, that I don't know exactly what to search for.

I have multiple progress bars, these are distinguishable by implementing a class:

```
<div class=\"progress_bar bar" + pbid + "\" value =\"100\">
```

Now, in JS, I try to adress them directly by their class:

```
function updatepb(pbid) {
    var val = $('.progress_bar.bar' + pbid).progressbar('value');
    val += 60;
    $('.progress_bar.bar' + pbid).progressbar('value', val);
};
```

This does not work.

If I adress the bars directly, e.g

```
$('.progress_bar.bar1').progressbar('value', val);
```

it works.

So the problem is basically just how to implement the variable.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? :-)

Comment: Why don't you use the `id` attribute for ids?

Comment: How do you call the `updatepb()` function? And does `pbid` get passed??

Comment: Where do the value of `pbid` come from respectively? Do they have the expected values?

Comment: Provided the div does end up with (say) `bar123` and you then query `.progress_bar.bar123`, the code above should work. Please post a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar).

Comment: Probably the value of     pbid is not set.

Comment: Add `if(!pbid)throw new Error('pbid is not set.');` to `function updatepb(pbid) {` and you will see why :-)

Comment: Indeed, that was the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is `pbid`? You may need to escape it.